# Databricks: convert data frame and export to xls / xlsx

Tags: excel, databricks

Is it possible for Databricks: convert data frame and export to xls / xlsx and save to blob storage ?
Using Python

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an Excel file?  CSV files are so much easier to work with.  You can certainly open a CSV into Excel, and save that as an Excel file.  As I know, you can write directly to the Blob storage, and completely bypass the step of storing the data locally.

```
df.write \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .save("myfile.csv")
```

In this example, you can try changing the extension to xls before you run the job.  I can't test this because I don't have Databricks setup on my personal laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of writing a dataframe to excel:

Using pyspark:

```
df.write   
.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")   
.option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet'!B3:C35")   
.option("useHeader", "true")   
.option("dateFormat", "yy-mmm-d") 
.option("timestampFormat", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss") 
.mode("append")
.save("Worktime2.xlsx")
```

Based upon this library: [spark-excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) by Crealytics.

The following way does not require as much maneuvering. First, you will convert your pyspark dataframe to a pandas data frame (toPandas()) and then use the "to_excel" to write to excel format.

```
import pandas
df.describe().toPandas().to_excel('fileOutput.xls', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index = False)
```

Note, the above requires xlwt package to be installed (pip install xlwt in the command line)

Comment: where exactly will it be stored in data bricks